# cassandra - queries to one table timing out...always

Tags: cassandra

Using apache cassandra 2.1 rc4... Used the datastax c# driver + entity context nuget package to auto create a schema. It created the relevant tables, and everything looks ok via cqlsh > describe. In dev centre, the schemas show up fine. However:

- There are 8 tables. All but one are behaving normally.
- One table times out for inserts and selects. Describe works fine.

There's hardly any data there - 100 or so rows. For the problematic table,

```
SELECT * FROM tbl;
```

times out.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where pk1='foo' and pk2='bar'
```

returns immediately with 0 rows. There doesn't seem to be any data in the table (makes sense...all inserts fail).

Upped the replication factor for the keyspace from one to three (4 node cluster, all nodes are healthy). Running a full repair on the keyspace (again...hardly any data there). Seems to be taking forever.

Any ideas?

Update:
I upped the replication factor of the keyspace to 3, ran a full repair (seemed to be endless), then ran a rolling restart on all nodes (triggered the rolling restart while the full repair was in progress). That seems to have fixed it. Something must have been caught in limbo or something. Here's the describe output:

```
CREATE TABLE vigil."tallyOrderScores" (
context text,
"orderRef" text,
"ruleId" int,
"ruleText" text,
score int,
PRIMARY KEY ((context, "orderRef"), "ruleId")
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ("ruleId" ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: Can you post the `DESCRIBE TABLE tbl` output from cqlsh?

Comment: try it from cqlsh with tracing enabled and include that text

Answer (score 0):

Did you run an older Cassandra before? In that case, you may need to run nodetool upgradesstables: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsUpgradeSstables.html